# Dynamically load in Angular template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, templates

I'm pretty new to Angular, so I think template is the wrong word.  Here's what I mean:

We have a Rails backend serving up data to an Angular frontend.  I need to use an `ng-repeat` to show off this data.  The problem is, the desired template comes as part of the data that Rails serves us.  Here's an example:

JSON served by Rails

```
[
  {
    data: {
      title: "example title",
      body: "example body"
    },
    template: "<h1>{{title}}</h1><p>{{body}}</p>"
  },
  {
    data: {
      body: "example body two"
    },
    template: "<div>{{body}}</div>"
  }
]
```

We don't know how many records there will be, what the templates will look like, or what bindings they call for (body, title, caption, etc).  I cannot store the templates locally, so all the data has to come from the Rails backend.

Here is pseudocode of what I'd like to accomplish:

```
<span ng-repeat="block in blocks">
  <template src="block.template" data="block.data"></template>
</span>
```

This would use the specified template and bind the `data` object to it.

---

Again, I'm new to angular so if I need to clarify let me know.  Thank you!

EDIT:  Here's my attempt at a directive.  It doesn't work since it appears that `template` doesn't have access to the desired template represented by `block.template`.  This wouldn't cover binding the data, so I'd have to work that in once I fixed the directive.

```
app.directive("template", function() {
  return {
    template: block.template,
    scope: {
        block: '=data'
    },
    restrict: 'E'
  };
});
```

EDIT 2:

Here's another attempt that doesn't work.  This one shows the template on screen, but in the console it errors that `scope.$watch is not a function`

```
app.directive('template', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      tmpl: '=template'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('tmpl', function (block) {
        element.html(block.template.blank_template);
        $compile(element.contents())(block.payload);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Maybe the use of [**ngBindHtml**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) would be useful in this case.

Comment: @developer033 I tried that, but it interpreted the bindings literally, so it said `{{ title }}` on the page instead of the desired data

Comment: Try *directives* then

Comment: Yeah use a directive.  You can set it up to listen for a particular url and load dynamically the template than $compile

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I looked into that, but I couldn't get $compile to compile a string. It seems to want a URL.

Comment: It looks for an element not a string.  I'll set you up with a simplified answer for an example

Comment: I updated the question with a simple attempt (that doesn't work).  Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a directive:

basically something along the lines of

```
//Assuming App is your Angular App Instance and Angular at least 1.4ish
app.directive('template',['$compile', function($c) {
      return {
         link: function (scope, el, attrs, controller) {
            el.html(scope.template);
            $c(el.contents())(scope);
         },
         scope: {
           template: "=tpl",
           data: "=data"
         }
      }
});
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
<span ng-repeat="block in blocks">
  <template tpl="block.template" data="block.data"></template>
</span>
```

Comment: I don't guarantee it is 100% error free, but it should give you an idea...

Comment: Thank you!  It doesn't seem to work, but I'll play around and see what I can do.  Question: in the scope object, you write `data: "=data"`, but `data` isn't used anywhere. Is that something Angular picks up on automatically?

Comment: data is passed on to the scope object of this instance so it then passes on to the template for binding.  To reference those values you need to reference it like: `{{data.title}}` etc.

Comment: Oh, so I'd need to change the templates to say {{ data.body }} instead of {{ body }}?

Comment: I believe so.  Maybe you can pass to the compile function instead of the scope object the scope.data object although again I'm not at my computer so I can't exactly test.  So `$c(el.contents())(scope.data)

Comment: Thanks again!  It doesn't work, but this is a great jumping off point.  If I fix it up tomorrow, I'll post here.

Comment: I updated the original question with another attempt at a directive.  It's closer to working, but it shows the unbound template on screen and says that `scope.$watch is not a function`.  Do you have any advice?